# Telerik PHP Kendo UI Grid/ForeignKey Column Demo Error

Tags: php, kendo-ui, telerik

After carefully writing the code from http://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/grid/foreignkeycolumn in my TestPage.php (just changing Database connection) and using the exactly file DaraSourceResult.php of the demo, it still came up with 2 bugs:

1) When the Grid renders, it brings the data from the Database but the ForeignKey Column comes blank.

2) If you click in the foreign key column, it successfully shows the CategoryNames from the Database, but it sill doesn't work when you select one category, probably becaue it's trying to use a text in a number field.

I've attached a picture showing each of the bugs described above. Also below it goes my code used in the TestPage.php.

Could you please give me a hand to fix these 2 bugs?

Thanks a lot!

[Picture with the bugs described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ5k0.jpg)

```
      <?php
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/Kendo/Autoload.php';
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lib/DataSourceResult.php';
    ?>


    <?php
    $result = new DataSourceResult('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', '******'); //ok


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        $type = $_GET['type'];
        $columns = array('PKEntrada', 'Descricao', 'Valor', 'FKCategoriaEntrada');
        switch($type) {
            case 'create':
                $result = $result->create('tblentradas', $columns, $request->models, 'PKEntrada');
                break;
            case 'read':
                $result = $result->read('tblentradas', $columns, $request);
                break;
            case 'update':
                $result = $result->update('tblentradas', $columns, $request->models, 'PKEntrada');
                break;
            case 'destroy':
                $result = $result->destroy('tblentradas', $request->models, 'PKEntrada');
                break;
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    }
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
        <link href="styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


<?php
$categories = $result->read('tblcategoriasentrada', array('PKCategoriaEntrada as value', 'Categoria as text'));


$transport = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransport();
$create = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportCreate();
$create->url('TestPage.php?type=create')
     ->contentType('application/json')
     ->type('POST');
$read = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportRead();
$read->url('TestPage.php?type=read')
     ->contentType('application/json')
     ->type('POST');
$update = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportUpdate();
$update->url('TestPage.php?type=update')
     ->contentType('application/json')
     ->type('POST');
$destroy = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportDestroy();
$destroy->url('TestPage.php?type=destroy')
     ->contentType('application/json')
     ->type('POST');
$transport->create($create)
          ->read($read)
          ->update($update)
          ->destroy($destroy)
          ->parameterMap('function(data) {
          return kendo.stringify(data);
      }');
$model = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModel();
$productIDField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('PKEntrada');
$productIDField->type('number')
               ->editable(false)
               ->nullable(true);
$productNameField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('Descricao');
$productNameField->type('string')
                 ->validation(array('required' => true));
$unitPriceValidation = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelFieldValidation();
$unitPriceValidation->required(true)
                    ->min(1);
$unitPriceField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('Valor');
$unitPriceField->type('number')
               ->validation($unitPriceValidation);
$categoryIDField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('FKCategoria');
$categoryIDField->type('number');


$model->id('PKEntrada')
    ->addField($productIDField)
    ->addField($productNameField)
    ->addField($unitPriceField)
    ->addField($categoryIDField);
$schema = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchema();
$schema->data('data')
       ->errors('errors')
       ->model($model)
       ->total('total');
$dataSource = new \Kendo\Data\DataSource();
$dataSource->transport($transport)
           ->batch(true)
           ->pageSize(30)
           ->schema($schema);
$grid = new \Kendo\UI\Grid('grid');
$productName = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$productName->field('Descricao')
            ->title('Description');
$unitPrice = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$unitPrice->field('Valor')
          ->format('{0:c}')
          ->width(200)
          ->title('Value');
$categoryID = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$categoryID->field('FKCategoria')
          ->title('FKCategory')
          ->values($categories['data'])
          ->width(200);
$command = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
$command->addCommandItem('destroy')
        ->title('&nbsp;')
        ->width(150);
$grid->addColumn($productName, $categoryID, $unitPrice, $command)
     ->dataSource($dataSource)
     ->addToolbarItem(new \Kendo\UI\GridToolbarItem('create'),
    new \Kendo\UI\GridToolbarItem('save'), new \Kendo\UI\GridToolbarItem('cancel'))
     ->height(540)
     ->navigatable(true)
     ->editable(true)
     ->groupable(true)
     ->pageable(true);
echo $grid->render();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error. I was just a problem with the Columns Fields names in the variables. Instead of using FKCategoriaEntrada, it was trying to use FKCategoria.

The code is running smooth now. You can use it if need.